# How to use BizTalk Server to forward an existing SOAP WebService?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I am new to BizTalk development. I have an existing SOAP web service, which has around 50 different operations. I want to connect this service to another application, but use the BizTalk server as an intermediary in this communication. So service and application should not know each other directly, BizTalk should be able to log all messages going through etc etc.

What is the best approach to make this work in BizTalk Server 2013?

So far I tried to create a new BizTalk Application and import the SOAP web service there. Then however it seems that I need to create around 50 different orchestrations, each one just mapping the incoming message in BizTalk to the external service for each service operation. This seems very cumbersome. Also publishing all those orchestrations becomes painful, as BizTalk cannot merge those into a single endpoint again. Ideally I would like to publish a single endpoint for BizTalk server on IIS that is using the exact same WSDL as the target SOAP service, ideally without having to create any orchestrations at all. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, yes, but...what you want is absolutely doable but there would be lots of answers for that.  Once you learn how things in BizTalk are actually working, it's obvious how to do this.

For example, a single Receive Location (IIS endpoint) can receive any number of request types provided they are the same protocol/format, SOAP, REST/JSON for example.  The only difference in the IIS site is any metadata, so just don't publish that.  The Message differentiation is done in the Pipelines just like any other BizTalk Message.

You don't really need Orchestrations for Maps, you can apply those at the Port Level provided it's a 1-1 relationship between the SOAP call and Map.

Please try a few things.  I'll become clear.  You can always come back for any specific issues.